# ActiveRecord - validation :allow_blank is always active even if it has :unless

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, activerecord

I have this model

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :type, :school_name, :school_grade

  validates :type, :inclusion =>{:in =>['1','2']}, :allow_blank => true
  validates :school_name,  :presence =>{:if => :student?}
  validates :school_grade, :numericality =>{:only_integer =>true}, :allow_blank => {:unless => :student?}

  def student?
    type.to_s == '1'
  end
end
```

I tried following patterns.

```
User.create(:type =>'2', :school_name =>nil, :school_grade =>nil)
```

=> OK. No error occurred.

```
User.create(:type =>'1', :school_name =>nil, :school_grade =>1)
```

=> OK. ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid error "school_name is empty" occurred.

```
User.create(:type =>'1', :school_name =>'foo', :school_grade =>'string is not a number')
```

=> OK. Validetion error "school_grade is not a number" occurred.

```
User.create(:type =>'1', :school_name =>'foo', :school_grade =>nil)
```

=> NG. I expect "school_grade is not a number" error, but no error occurred.

I tried this pattern also, but got same result.

```
  validates :school_grade, :numericality =>{:only_integer =>true}, :allow_blank => {:if => :not_student?}

  def not_student?
    type.to_s != '1'
  end
```

I guess validation :allow_blank is always active, but why? And how to fix it?

Thank you.

Comment: what is the datatype of `type` in the DB?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`allow_blank` does not accept a `Hash`, only a boolean, so you cannot write something like `:allow_blank => {:unless => :student?}`, as you can see in the source activemodel-4.1.2/lib/active_model/validator.rb

```
def validate(record)
  attributes.each do |attribute|
    value = record.read_attribute_for_validation(attribute)
    next if (value.nil? && options[:allow_nil]) || (value.blank? && options[:allow_blank])
    validate_each(record, attribute, value)
  end
end
```

However what you want to achieve can be done in two lines:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :school_grade, :if => :student?
  validates :school_grade, :numericality =>{:only_integer =>true}, :allow_blank => true
end
```

Comment: This code works for me. But I got `validates_presence_of is deprecated in Rails`, so I changed like this.
  
`validates :school_grade, :presence =>true, :if => :student?`
  
Thank you.

Comment: Good. But now I'm curious and worry about my set-up cause in Rails 4.1.2 I do not get any depreciation warning. I googled and found that depreciation for `validates_presence_of` was in Rails 3. Which version are you using?

Comment: Also in current git version I cannot see any depreciation related code https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/0df1f914104073b70f8d8976d0d5adc3b2a1e44e/activemodel/lib/active_model/validations/presence.rb#L34

Comment: I'm using Rails 3.2.18. Thank you for your information. It became helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want the allow_blank to be conditional or the whole numericallity validation?

If the latter:

```
validates :school_grade, :numericality =>{:only_integer =>true}, :allow_blank => true, :unless => :student?
validates :school_grade, :numericality =>{:only_integer =>true}, :allow_blank => false, :if => :student?
```

Comment: This code allows not integer param when `student?` is `false`. I want to reject it but only when `student?` is `false`, want to allow `nil`. Thank you.

Comment: I updated my answer. Do two validations for school_grade. One for the student case one for the not student case.

Comment: Latest code works well. But Benjamin's is simpler because there are other validations in my real code. Thank you anyway.